# Я 11(-го) числа её поздравлю

Tags: наращение

Здесь наращение не нужно:

> Я 11 января её поздравлю.

А здесь нужно?

> Я 11(-го) числа её поздравлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наращение используется:

*Я 11-го числа еë поздравлю*.

Об этом здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]